# Indexed view to optimize search over multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, search, indexed-view

I have a question concerning an idea I have about optimizing performance of a complex search query. This is the situation:

Base table, with the fields to search on:

```
Server (uniqueNumber, serverName, hostName)
```

Tables to join, with the fields to search on:

```
Customer (Company, vatNumber)
CustomerContact (firstName, lastName, email, telephone, mobile)
Ip (ipAddress)
```

The idea I had was to create an indexed view like this:

```
viewServers (ServerID, Term)
```

(clustered index on ServerID, non-clustered on Term)

which is a union of all possible data:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.ServerID AS ServerID, c.Company AS Term FROM Customer c 
        INNER JOIN Server s ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    UNION
    SELECT s.ServerID AS ServerID, c.vatNumber AS Term FROM Customer c 
        INNER JOIN Server s ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    UNION
    SELECT s.ServerID AS ServerID, c.firstName AS Term FROM CustomerContact cc 
        INNER JOIN Customer s ON s.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN Server s ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    UNION
    SELECT s.ServerID AS ServerID, i.ipAddress AS Term FROM Ip i 
        INNER JOIN Server s ON i.ServerID = i.ServerID
    UNION
) AS result ORDER BY Term
```

When I want to search, I was planning to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Server WHERE ServerID IN (SELECT ServerID FROM viewServers WHERE Term LIKE @Term
```

Good or bad idea?

Comment: You should look at full text indexing rather than indexed views for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if it's a good or bad idea without knowing a lot of other things about your database. And indexed view will probably help that particular query but may hurt other database operations. Also, it's not a great idea to create a non-unique clustered index (ServerID).